# How to extract region information from aws s3 virtual path uri using regex using java?

Tags: java, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I need to extract region information from s3 virtual based path uri as follows.
https://<bucket_name>.s3.<region_name>..com/

My intention is to fetch the region name from s3 uri and provide the region while creation s3client using aws java sdk 2.x.

Can anyone help me with the regex for this?

Comment: If your java code is running on the same region your s3 bucket is created, you can use the environment variable AWS_REGION instead

Comment: Yeah that's true. My scenario is I don't want the user to mention the region explicitly and should be extracted by program itself

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://mybucket.s3.us-west-1.com/";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("https:\\/\\/.*\\.s3\\.(.*)\\.com");

        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(url);

        if(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

`matcher.group(0)` will give you the entire match (the full URL in this case). Calling `matcher.group(1)` will get the first matched group, that is the first part of the regex encapsuled in `()`

Comment: thanks for your response. I changed  "https:\\/\\/.*\\.s3\\.(.*)\\.(.*)" to make it bit general. Many thanks again

Comment: I want to match the strings like https://mybucket.s3.us-west-1.(xxx)*.com, i.e after region there can be more than one subdomain. can you please give me some suggestion on this?

Comment: Maybe you can go with something like this `https:\\/\\/.*\\.s3\\.([^.]*)\\.?(.*)?\\.com` . The first group will capture every string that dont have a dot character, the second group will match something between the first group and the .com part. You can test it here https://regex101.com/r/57kNQP/1